# Swing: process JFileChooser result after action?

Tags: java, swing, action, jfilechooser

I want to use an Abstract action for JFileChooser buttons because there will be dozens of these.

```
public class OpenFileAction extends AbstractAction {
JFrame frame;
JFileChooser chooser;

OpenFileAction(JFrame frame, JFileChooser chooser) {
    super("Open...");
    this.chooser = chooser;
    this.frame = frame;
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
    // Show dialog; this method does not return until dialog is closed
    chooser.showOpenDialog(frame);
}
};
```

Obviously I want to write the JFileChooser result to a variable. How can I access e.getSource() AFTER the action is finished? This does not work because it is triggered before the FileChooser Dialog opens:

```
    JButton btnNewButton_1 = new JButton(new OpenFileAction(new JFrame(), new JFileChooser(new File(".")) ) );
    btnNewButton_1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            //process e.getSource() ?
        }
    });
```

Comment: I don't really understand what you're trying to do. Why are you creating a button with your action (first action listener), and add a second action listener to the button just after? What's your end goal?

Comment: I need to get the value from the file chooser somehow. Given that I have to know the result of the OpenFileAction, how would one do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you're after is the following:

```
public abstract class OpenFileAction extends AbstractAction {
    JFrame frame;
    JFileChooser chooser;

    public OpenFileAction(JFrame frame, JFileChooser chooser) {
        super("Open...");
        this.chooser = chooser;
        this.frame = frame;
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        int option = chooser.showOpenDialog(this.frame);
        if (option == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            File selectedFile = chooser.getSelectedFile();
            doWithSelectedFile(selectedFile)
        }
    }

    /**
     * Method to override, which gets called with the selected file.
     */
    protected abstract doWithSelectedFile(File file);
}

...

OpenFileAction action = new OpenFileAction(frame, new JFileChooser(new File("."))) {
    @Override
    protected void doWithSelectedFile(File file) {
        // do what you want here
    }
};
JButton button = new JButton(action);
```

Comment: You can override the method of another class via the constructor? woah. That looks like it will work. Thanks!

Comment: It's exactly the same thing as what you're doing when you create a new anonymous ActionListener as you're doing in your question: you're creating an anonymous subclass of OpenFileAction.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an update of your code showing how you can work this out. Your action listener is not needed since you already set an `Action` on the JButton (which is also an ActionListener).

```
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.io.File;

import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class TestFileChooser {

    public static class OpenFileAction extends AbstractAction {
        JFileChooser chooser;

        OpenFileAction(JFileChooser chooser) {
            super("Open...");
            this.chooser = chooser;
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
            int retval = chooser.showOpenDialog((Component) evt.getSource());
            if (retval == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                File selectedFile = chooser.getSelectedFile();
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog((Component) evt.getSource(), "You have chosen " + selectedFile.getAbsolutePath());
            }
        }
    };

    protected void initUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test file chooser");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser(new File("."));
        JButton btnNewButton_1 = new JButton(new OpenFileAction(chooser));
        frame.add(btnNewButton_1);
        frame.setSize(600, 400);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new TestFileChooser().initUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Here is the tutorial on [JFileChooser](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html) which may provide additional information.

Comment: Thanks, but I was hoping to have the file chooser in a separate class really, which was the whole point of the abstraction. This is kinda my code right now. I wanted to access the ActionEvent because you can never be sure if JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION was called and all from outside the class...

Comment: @user70448 what is preventing you from making retval a member of your OPenFileAction class and adding a getter for that value?

Comment: nothing preventing me from it, but how would I call the getter from outside after the action is done?

Comment: @user70448 I don't understand what is blocking you. In the code I provided above, instead of opening a JOptionPane indicating which file was selected, put your code to do something with the selected file. If you want that class to be reusable, follow JB Nizet's suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:**

the following code is apt for you:

```
JButton openButton = new JButton();
openButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    public void actionPerformed(evt){
        final JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
        File openFile;
        if(fileChooser.showOpenDialog(frame) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
            openFile= fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
        //place your code here
    }
});
```

**OR** (if you absolutely need a local method)

```
JButton openButton = new JButton();
openButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    public void actionPerformed(evt){
        final JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
        if(fileChooser.showOpenDialog(frame) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
            openButtonActionPerformed(fileChooser.getSelectedFile());
    }
});
openButtonActionPerformed(File openFile){
    //place your code here
}
```

There are no need to create another class

Comment: Thanks, but this is using a JButton to call the FileChooser.

Comment: just place this code inside your jButtonActionPerformed method and you are done