# How to open a text file using openFileChooser

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener, jfilechooser

I am trying to open a file from a menu button but I'm unable to find a suitable way to do this with a action listener. what additions would I need to make to this code to do this?

```
private void jMenuItem1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    int returnValue = openFileChooser.showOpenDialog(this);
    if (returnValue == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "This a vaild file", 
                                            "Display Message", 
                                            JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    }
    else {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No file was selected", 
                                            "Display Message",
                                            JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    }
}
```

Comment: see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html, `openFileChooser.getSelectedFile();`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Swing: process JFileChooser result after action?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11257593/swing-process-jfilechooser-result-after-action)

Comment: Thanks this helped point me in the right direction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume that you know how to create UI already. So firstly you need to define a JFileChooser object:

```
//Create a file chooser as final
final JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
```

In your event method just need to handle the action:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    //Handle open button action.
    if (e.getSource() == openButton) {
        int returnVal = fc.showOpenDialog(YourClassName.this);
        if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            File file = fc.getSelectedFile();
            //What to do with the file here.                
        } else {                
        }
    }
}
```

Refer this link for more detail info: [OracleFileChooserDocument](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html)

Comment: Thanks this helped me figure out what I need to do. Below is code for how I got this to work

Answer (score -1):

I was able to make this work the code below will allow you to select a file from the file chooser and will then display the file.

```
private void jMenuItem1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
    JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
    fileChooser.setCurrentDirectory(new File(System.getProperty("user.home")));
    int result = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(this);
    if (result == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
    File selectedFile = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
    System.out.println("Selected file: " + selectedFile.getAbsolutePath());
    try {
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("rundll32 url.dll,FileProtocolHandler " + selectedFile.getAbsolutePath());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error");
    }
}
    }
```

Comment: 1) `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("rundll32 url.dll,FileProtocolHandler " + selectedFile.getAbsolutePath());` instead use `Desktop.getDesktop().open(selectedFile);` 2) Use a logical and consistent form of indenting code lines and blocks.  The indentation is intended to make the flow of the code easier to follow! Most IDEs have a keyboard shortcut specifically for formatting code.